# Returning 'mObscuringWindow=null' when trying to do adb shell dumpsys and the target device has chrome open

Tags: android, google-chrome, adb, robotframework

I was trying to do some automation via chrome browser of a certain android device but when im doing '`adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mObscuringWindow'`' in the terminal and the device is currently displaying chrome browser, it returns '`null`'. But if I try it on other apps, it returns the appPackage and the appActivity. This happens on both physical and virtual device. Can somebody please help me?